# PHP - Create check box by using the records from MySQL datebase as values

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

i am a newbie in php programming and i cant figure out where i have gone wrong as my php code wont execute.

As the title says i am trying to create check boxes in my site however the values will come from the mysql database.

I have a table named “campus” in MySQL database and it has 2 coloumns called id and room.

database
[![Database][1]][1]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaBuG.png

current output
[![Current Output][2]][2]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/64XxE.png

below is my code:

```
<?PHP

$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$databaseName = "my computer";

$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);


// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }



?>


<html>  
<body>


<form name="aform">


Choose a room:


<?php
  $s = '';
  $j = 0;
  if ($q = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM `campus`")) {
    while ($line = $q->fetch_assoc()) {
      $s.= '<input type="checkbox" name="car'.$j.'" value="'.$line['room'].'">';
    }
  }
  echo $s;
?>

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what have you get so far?

Comment: hi, i do not understand your question?

Comment: Every checkbox has the same name. Is that what you want?

Comment: hi, yes everycheck box has the same name

Answer (score 1):

You're not closing the while loop properly. Close the while loop as follow.

```
<?php

    $sql = "SELECT room FROM campus";
    $result = mysqli_query($sql);

    while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    ?>

    <input type="checkbox" name="car" value="<?php echo $line['room']?>" />

   <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for that correction, however even after that correction my code doesn't seem to execute? do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Doesn't it needs to be `$line['room']` ?

Comment: What is the output you're getting ? Turn on error and warning log in PHP. Paste the output in your question please.

Comment: @Chay22 suggested try $line['room'] instead of $line[room]

Comment: hi, i have tried the $line['room'] but that still doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: as for error or warning, i dont seem to get those either ... all im outputing is the "choose a room" text from the html

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT room FROM campus";
$result = mysqli_query($sql);

$campusArray = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($campusArray as $campus): ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="car" value="<?php echo $campus['room'];?>" />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I hope with this you can solve your problem.

> alternative syntax is excellent for improving legibility (for both PHP
> and HTML!) in situations where you have a mix of them.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: hi,i tried you code however the output seems to be the same. it just outputs blank page

Comment: add `$dbCon` to `mysqli_query` now, first, add this code after the first php tag `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` `ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);` `error_reporting(E_ALL);` then run your code, if that show an error post it, if not check with partial code, first remove all html the code and run it, then add only the query, not the foreach, and run and check the output of $resutl, then add the fetch and check the output of $campusArray, and you will be able to see the error.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to PHP!

An error is that you're missing the semicolon that's needed after any php function (such as echo)

```
<?php echo $line['room']; ?>
```

And there's the missing PHP tags around the closing }

A third error is that you're not telling mysqli which connection to run the query on it should have:

```
mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
```

Apart from that it looks good, personally I prefer to use a PDO connection but mysqli is still good, but there are a few formatting tricks that can help prevent problems.

For example it's always a good idea to use back-ticks (`)

So:

```
$sql = "SELECT `room` FROM `campus`";
```

However, for this it might be best to use the * query. Which selects everything from the column so:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `campus`";
```

The reason is how you're getting the data, you're telling PHP to create an array using the results.. but you've only given it one piece of data for each row. So if you give it all of the data it just makes it a little easier to use.

Here's the full code:

```
<?php $dbCon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "my computer");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}?>    
<html>  
    <body>
        <form name="aform">
            Choose a room:
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `campus`";
            $result = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);

            while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
                <input type="checkbox" name="car" value="<?php echo $line['room']; ?>"
            <?php } ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, if you're interested, here's how it'd be done in PDO:

```
<?php
try{
    $con = new \PDO("mysql:host=" . 'localhost' . ";dbname=" . 'My Computer', 'root', 'root');
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Connection Failed";
    die();
} ?>
<html>  
    <body>
        <form name="aform">
            Choose a room:
            <?php
            $result = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `campus`")
            $result->execute();
            while ($row = $result->fetch()) { ?>
                <input type="checkbox" name="car" value="<?php echo $row['room']; ?>"
           <?php } ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Still not working? Feel free to comment and I'll see what's up :)

Thanks,
P110

Comment: hi P110, i corrected all the mistakes that you pointed out in my code but the output seems to be the same?.

Comment: i also tired your new code with the PDO, however that outputs a completely blank page with not even the html text

Comment: i have updated my code above according to ur comments

Comment: That is strange, the PDO thing probably means you don't have PDO installed which isn't a huge deal since you're not using it. Have you got error reporting turned on? Could you put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your code, it should then tell you what's going wrong? If you get an error out could you please post it here. Thanks :)

Comment: Since it's not outputting the checkboxes it would make me think it's not getting any results... which shouldn't be happening.. hmm

Comment: I've made a complete copy of your code and tried to copy your database as best I can and the code is working for me

Comment: hi can you send me the code that you made a copy of that you tired and worked

Comment: It's just the one in the answer, the one that uses mysqli :) There may be a different database setup or something?

Comment: is it much different than yours?

Comment: Yeah that's the one I copied.. hmm it shouldn't cause a problem at all if the connection is being made properly.. you're sure that mysql is up and running when you're connecting?

Comment: hi, yes mysql is up and running when im connecting....anyway thankyou for your help so far... i guess ill have to try to figure out myself whats rong with my code

Comment: Maybe you could try see if Mysql gives anything? Try adding `echo mysqli_error($dbCon);` and see if you get any errors back? (after the query has been run)

Comment: Try adding the error code that @Pablo gave you in a comment right at the top and see if that gets anything? There should be an error somewhere.

Comment: Hi @katetango did you ever get anywhere with this?